# 3d объект на 2d сцене

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли такое сделать? Есть поле, и на нем должен появляться 3д объект, само поле в 2д, камера сверху. Будет ли взаимодействовать физика 3д объекта с 2д полем?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать такое можно. Но физика 2д и 3д физика игнорируют друг друга. В зависимости от перспективы, может сработать 2д коллайдры на 3д объекте.

Comment: У поля вообще никакой физики не планируется, нужно только чтобы 3д объект по нему катился и немного подпрыгивал (Типо мячик)

Comment: Все верно, но чтобы по полю катился мячик, на нем должен быть коллайдр, а значит его должна видеть физика. То же самое касается и мячика. Судя по тому что вы описали, трехмерные объектов и камеры смотрящей с верху будет более чем достаточно. п.с. не забудьте rigidbody для мячика

Comment: Значит нужно на поле повесить 2д колайдер, а на мячик риджитбоди и все должно работать, я правильно понял?

Comment: Нет. Или 2д физика, или 3д физика.  На поле - (BoxCollider) на мячик SphereCollider и Rigidbody. Будет катиться